# Links not clickable?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, z-index

I'm making a simple launchpage for class, but now some of my links aren't clickable. The Home link is fine,but all the other links won't respond to a click or hover.

See the live page [here](http://ahays.lindenweb.us/klh165).

Comment: Put your html code and launchpage.css file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css, do this:

```
nav {
    z-index: 1; //this line matters
    margin-top: -10px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Not sure why you have a -10 there

Answer (score 0):

In  css you have z-index:-10 and it should be 0 or greater

```
nav {
    z-index: 10;
    margin-top: -10px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```